# Mobility (Current Electricity)

Tags: electricity, electric-current

I was reading mobility in current electricity and there it was written that **the direction of conventional current due to positive and negative current carriers** is in the same direction but I cannot understand how and why?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a convention. Earlier it was assumed that positive charges travel to form current. But, it is now well known that electrons are the one which moves within a wire in opposite direction. This flow is equivalent to flow positive charges and we can assume that positive charges are moving and our equations are still valid.

Comment: Actually I made a typo.. where there is written charges there is actually current carriers.. how can be the direction of current through positive and negative carriers be the same?

Comment: When negative charges flow, they create a positive cavity in metal lattice. This cavity is filled by other current carries and it appears like positive charge is moving.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have the positive position axis going to the right. If I apply an electric field to the right, positive charges go right (they have a positive velocity) and negative charges go left (they have a negative velocity).

Current is the total charge that passes a surface area in some unit time. That can be found by the charge of the particle times the number density of charges that cross a surface area times the surface area times the average velocity of the charges.

$I_{pos}$ = (+q) * n * A * (+v) = a positive.

$I_{neg}$ = (-q) * n * A * (-v) = a positive.

Positive means that the current is going to the right. They are both positive and hence both going in the same direction.

Comment: Is the formula for current also given by charge times no density times area times velocity? Cuz i have just studied it as charge/time until now